# NetGear A6100 AC600 wireless adapter not working in Ubuntu 20.04. Worked fine in 18.04. Not same problem as previously

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

Firstly, I know very well there are answers to this already. But, in my case, it is installed and shows in the terminal as such `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]`

It says it is installed in [Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UliGO.png) as well.

I have tried downloading the driver for this adapter from several guides online, linking to GitHub, but no luck there either...

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The answer from `sudo dkms status` command reads:

`rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed`

The other command

`modinfo 8812au | grep 9052`

spits out the following:

`alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the termina command: `sudo dkms status` and also: `modinfo 8812au | grep 9052`

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from my USB stick, still the wireless won't work after installation... as in 18.04. This is really strange... maybe Ubuntu 20.04 is unsupported by the NetGear A6100 AC600?

Comment: It appears that you have two possibly conflicting driver versions installed. Check: does this command produce results? `modinfo rtl8812au | grep 9052` ?

Comment: After a reinstallation of Ubuntu 20.04, `modinfo 8812au | grep 9052` now gives `alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: I'm sorry, to answer your question chili, it gives nothing found.

Comment: So after reinstallation, it appears that you have the appropriate driver installed. Does the interface appear in `iwconfig`? Are there any clues here? `rfkill list all` or `dmesg | grep -i rtl`

Comment: `iwconfig` gives `enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions. lo        no wireless extensions.`

`rfkill list all` gives `0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no 

`dmesg | grep -i rtl` gives a very long wall of text.

Comment: Please paste the text here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Alright @chili555, here's a link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RqtWdP38Ks/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108517/discussion-between-chili555-and-skull-kid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circa-2014 driver doesn't operate correctly as we see in your various pastes. Let's remove it and try a better driver:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg --all
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.