# Netgear A6100 USB wifi-dongle - Has anyone ever got this to work?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, realtek

So i have a Netgear A6100 Wifi usb-dongle hooked up to my PC as I don't have, nor able to have, ethernet to my computer currently. I recently installed Ubuntu (studio) 20.04 and am now trying to get the Wifi to work. I've found multiple guides on how to get this to work, using gits and the make-command.

The problem is; none of the guides I've followed has led to success, rather giving me more headache than earlier... 99% of the times I get some various errors when running the make commands, other times everything seems fine, but wifi still does not work.

Has anyone here actually got this dongle to work with ubuntu? I'd expect it to work, since it works fine both on Windows 10 on the same machine and previously also with a RaspberryPi 2 running raspbian or volumio.

The dongle is based on the Realtek RTL8811AU chip and is detected by the system, as seen when running the lsusb-command:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
```

Comment: Did you try this accepted and, presumably working answer? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243616/netgear-a6100-ac600-wireless-adapter-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-worked-fine-in Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Nope, hadn't tried. Tried just now, and couldn't even get to the fourth step, i.e. "sudo ./dkms-install.sh", since there is no such file in the gib I just cloned.

Comment: Low and behold, checked the readme from that gib as a desperate try to find a solution and I tried to run the command "sudo make dkms-install" followed by "sudo modprobe 88XXAU" and *bam* it's finally working!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: However, now, next morning, when I booted the machine again, its not working again. Tried doing it from scratch again but end up with "modprobe:FATAL: module 88XXau not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-41-lowlatency" please help!!

Comment: Were there any errors or warnings in the `sudo make dkms_install` step? Are there any clues, errors, etc. in /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/5.8.0-41-low-latency/x86_64/log/make.log